# Are there infinitely many primes p such that both p-1 and p+1 have at most 3 prime factors, counted with multiplicity?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a subsequence of primes $p$ for which $p^2-1$ has at most 6 prime divisors counted with multiplicity.

This sequence described in the question is the sequence [A079153 in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A079153).

I could not find references on the first sequence, but I found a mention of the second sequence in another MO question:
[Number of prime factors of the order of a finite non-abelian simple group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67671/number-of-prime-factors-of-the-order-of-a-finite-non-abelian-simple-group) with a reference to a survey article by [Solomon from 2001](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-03/S0273-0979-01-00909-0/S0273-0979-01-00909-0.pdf): are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $|PSL(2,p)|=(p-1)*p*(p+1)/2$ is a product of six prime factors? In the survey article it is said this problem is akin to the twin prime conjecture, but no references are given.

Comment: The statement that $p^2-1$ has at most 6 prime factors (with multiplicity) is weaker than the statement that both $p-1$ and $p+1$ have most 3 prime factors (with multiplicity). For example, if $p-1$ has 2 prime factors and $p+1$ has 4 prime factors (with multiplicity), then the first statement is true, while the second is false.

Comment: just to make sure I understand the previous comment with a specific example, say $p=23$ so then $p-1=22=2*11$ and $p+1=24=2*2*2*3$, thus $p^2-1$ has 6 prime divisors (with multiplicity) while $p-1$ has only 2, and $p+1$ has 4. Is that right (and if so, should then the OP question be clarified)?

Comment: Both of you are of course quite right. I am editing my question.

Comment: Dickson's conjecture would imply that there are infinitely many members of the subsequence where, e.g.,  $(p-1)/6$ and $(p+1)/4$ are prime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the present time, the best (general) result is due to James Maynard, who has proven that any admissible 3-tuple takes at most 7 prime factors infinitely often (see [this paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9030782&fileId=S0305004113000339)).  In particular, (using a certain admissible 3-tuple related to what Robert Israel wrote) we can get that $n(n^2-1)$ has at most 11 prime factors infinitely often.

I don't know if this number can be improved for the specific case you are interested in.  However, the general consensus is that Dickson's conjecture is true, so both $p-1$ and $p+1$ *should* consist of exactly 3 prime factors, for infinitely many $p$.  But this conjecture is currently out of reach of any known techniques, and appears to be harder than the twin prime conjecture, since we must control admissible 3-tuples, but the twin prime problem deals with only admissible 2-tuples.

Comment: The result of James Maynard is much stronger than the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: No, it is not. Why do you say it is?