# Number of prime factors of the order of an increasing sequence of finite non-abelian simple group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I recently come across this question: [Number of prime factors of the order of a finite non-abelian simple group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67671/number-of-prime-factors-of-the-order-of-a-finite-non-abelian-simple-group). What caught my attention is the second question:

> *Does there exist a sequence $\{S_n\}$
> of non-abelian simple groups such that $|S_n|$
> goes to infinity and $\{\omega(|S_n|)\}$
> is bounded?* ($\omega(m)$ being the number of distinct prime factors of $m$, e.g., $\omega(12)=2$)

It seems that at the moment we are not able to answer it, but what happen if we add the additional requirement that the sequence $\{S_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is strictly ascending? (that is, $S_n$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of $S_{n+1}$? Is anything known in this case? I feel it should be easier to find an answer in this case, but I came with nothing at hand.

Comment: "Being a subgroup" is maybe not always natural, as opposed to "being a subquotient". For instance, the standard embedding $\mathrm{SL}_n\to\mathrm{SL}_{n+1}$ does not induce an embedding from $\mathrm{PSL}_n$ into $\mathrm{PSL}_{n+1}$.

Comment: @YCor I know, in fact "subgroup" is a way stronger requirement in this case than "subquotient", but that's why I feel it should be possible to prove the result in this case (to give a negative answer in fact)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if $p$ is a prime such that $6p+1$ and $12p+1$ are also primes then $|PSL(2,12p+1)|=12p(6p+1)(12p+1)$ has only five distinct prime factors. It would follow from the Generalised Bunyakovsky Conjecture that there are infinitely many of these, and they do seem pretty dense. For example between $10^{15}$ and $10^{15}+10^6$ there are $137$ of them, the first few of which are 1000000000007651, 1000000000012933, 1000000000021171, 1000000000026271, ...

Comment: Between $10^{50}$ and $10^{50}+10^6$ there are still six of them.